# ajax compatibility issues with firefox

Tags: php, ajax, firefox, browser

Hi I have created a website that has a form which actions directs to paypal payment. Before directing to paypal page, I created an ajax script that will read an external php file which will save my other data in the form to the database before directing to paypal. I got it work with IE and chrome, but for some reasons, which I don't know why it will not save the data using Firefox 20.0.1.

**What I want is that I want to get it work in *Firefox*. Since this code runs in IE and Chrome.**

**Heres my internal ajax script:**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#senrollnow').on('submit', function (e) {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'insert.php',
            data: $('#senrollnow').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted'+data);
            }
          });
        });
      });
</script>
```

**My HTML Form (index.php):**

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" name="ligit" method="POST" id="senrollnow" target="_top" >
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="large-12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="large-6 columns">
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" required />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="large-6 columns">
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" required />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="large-12 columns">
                                            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="large-12 columns">          

                                            <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Courses Options">Courses Options
                                            <select name="os0">
                                                <option value="Basic (30 mins)">Basic (30 mins) : $69.00 AUD - monthly</option>
                                                <option value="Basic (1 hour)">Basic (1 hour) : $129.00 AUD - monthly</option>
                                                <option value="Standard (30 mins)">Standard (30 mins) : $69.00 AUD - monthly</option>
                                                <option value="Standard (1 hour)">Standard (1 hour) : $129.00 AUD - monthly</option>
                                                <option value="International (30 mins)">International (30 mins) : $69.00 AUD - monthly</option>
                                                <option value="International (1 hour)">International (1 hour) : $129.00 AUD - monthly</option>
                                            </select> 
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br/>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="large-12 large-centered columns text-center">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD">
                                            <input class="pulse-shrink" type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
                                            <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                                            <!--<input id="button_enroll" type="submit" name="ligit" placeholder="Email" class="button" value="Enrol Now!" /> -->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

**And my PHP: insert.php**

```
require_once "dbconfig.php";

// escape variables for security
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['first_name']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['last_name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$type = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['os0']);

$date = date_create();
$created = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');

$sql="INSERT INTO student (first_name, last_name, email, type, created)
VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$type', '$created')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

header('Location: index.php');
```

Comment: have you tried using firebug to see if the ajax call is being triggered and if there are any errors being returned

Comment: actually i haven't use firebug, since I'm new in developing and used chrome F12 a lot. anyways I'll try to use that one and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as I understand you want to load some data to form before submitting it and after them sent form data by default way

I thing you must to do actions send form to paypal and to your server separately.
One way is to send ajax form and call event.preventDefault() to prevent default submitting form
and on success callback you may do submitting.

the simplest primitive way is to add a class to form e.g.

```
$('#senrollnow').on('submit', function (e) {
      var form = $(this);
      if(!form.hasClass('pending')) {
          e.preventDefault();
          form.addClass('pending');
          $.ajax({
              type: 'post',
              url: 'insert.php',
              data: $('#senrollnow').serialize(),
              success: function () {
                form.submit();
                // alert('form was submitted'+data);
              }
          });
      }
});
```

Comment: This is a good solution, this manage to insert data to the database. The problem now is when I try to test it in chrome, I will not stop inserting data to my database and does not proceed with the action.

Comment: great, very useful man. I will study what you have done here. thanks.

Comment: so logic is that when user click submit - browser call this handler and first time form has no class "pending". we mark form as pending, call preventDefault() - stop native browser behavior, call ajax (save data) and after trigger submit (imitate it). as form already has class "pending" handler nothing to do and browser does native thinks (sent form by default action and method was specified)